# Vis js not working on IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, vis.js

I was trying to run [this](http://visjs.org/examples/network/basicUsage.html) basic vis.js example. It runs fine on Chrome and Firefox but while running on internet explorer 10 it gave me the error:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'emitter' of undefined or null reference
vis.js, line 34467 character 7
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Please tell me what's a possible fix for this?

Comment: Did u fix that? I have the same problem.

Comment: Try in configuration to set:
`edges: {
    ...
    smooth: {
      ....
      type: 'continuous',
      ...
}
  }`.
'dynamic' smooth is not supported in IE maybe. Try with some else.

I fix in this way 'emitter' problem, but it continues to doesn't works with other problem.
I will continue and I let u know

Comment: I fixed downgrading vis.js to 1.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Vis.js does not support IE9-IE10](https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/1839). You could try downgrading e.g. to [vis.js@4.12.0](https://github.com/almende/vis/releases/tag/v4.12.0).

Comment: I've tested a simple network examples, and the issue only starts appearing in versions 4.16.0 and then 4.16.1. Up to 4.15.0, examples work.

Answer (score 1):

In [vis.js@4.18.1](https://github.com/almende/vis/releases/tag/v4.18.1) , issue seems fixed.